# Please let me know working mechanism of poll(CRON JOB) in Apache Camel

Tags: cron, apache-camel

```
file://D:/Users/schintha/temp/input?autoCreate=false&include=.*.csv|.*.CSV|.*.eof|.*.EOF
&maxMessagesPerPoll=1000&moveFailed=.error&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=0+*+*+*+*+?
&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&sortBy=file:modified;ignoreCase:file:name
```

I am using above Route with poll(cron scheduler) is at every 0 second (once in a minute).

if file(s) (i.e.,one or more files) transfer takes more than one minute then sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle will work or not is my question
.
Since, i am stopping route when there is no file during the poll.

Please let me know the functionality of poll(cron scheduler)if file transfer takes more than poll time (i.e., more than one minute in this case)

Structure of my route:

```
<route>
<from>
<when>
<simple>${headers.CamelBatchSize} >= 1  and ${body} != null 
and ${headers.CamelFileName} != null</simple>
<to>
<otherwise> <toD uri="controlbus:route?routeId=${routeId}&amp;action=stop"/>    
</route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about what the question is?

The `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle`option will only send an empty message body if the current poll didn't find any files to process. If the poll finds a file and it takes more than one minute to process all that happens is that a new poll will execute in parallel to the one that's already in progress.

I.e. you won't get an empty message if the current poll takes more than a minute to finish.

Also, if the only thing you want to do if there are no files to process is to stop the route you might as well just remove `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle` altogether. If that option is set to false (which it is by default) the route will stop automatically (until the next poll, that is).

Comment: you won't get an empty message if the current poll takes more than a minute to finish.... please explain in detail
i.e., file was already picked and  camel is transferring file , there is no file in new poll .so i hope t should send "emptymessage"